# Retrieving exit code of yum install from "pbrun -c" command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, powerbroker

I'm trying to retrieve the exit code from a yum install using "pbrun bash -c" command, but I'm having issues, since when I try to get it executing it from pbrun, it gives exit satus 0 (which is wrong, because I know it failed):

```
[user@server ~]$ pbrun bash -c "timeout 10s yum -y install NessusAgent.x86_64; echo $?"
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
0
[user@server ~]$ pbrun bash
[root@server ~]# timeout 10s yum -y install NessusAgent.x86_64; echo $?
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
124
```

In this case, why is it giving exit code 0 instead of 124 when executing it from "pbrun bash -c" command?

Comment: Did you tried `exit $?` at the end instead of `echo $?`?

Comment: @Bayou I just tried that and it doesn't return anything

Comment: I don't know a lot about `pbrun`, but [it seems](https://www.beyondtrust.com/docs/archive/privilege-management/powerbroker/unix-linux/9-2/pbul-admin-9-2.pdf) that the exit status is not logged in "local mode". Perhaps you can check the link, because they do speak of returning an exit status in the document.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to the parameter expansion of bash. Since you are using double quotes in your command, `$?` is expanded *before* the command is executed, which means the exit code you are seeing is the exit code of the previous command.

Try changing to:

```
pbrun bash -c 'timeout 10s yum -y install NessusAgent.x86_64; echo $?'
```